# Bounded operator with 1-dimensional image

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is a problem I encountered:

> Suppose $T$ is a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose $\text{im }T=\text{span}\{y\}$.
>
> i. Prove that there exists $h\in H$ so that $Tx=\langle x,h\rangle y$ for all $x\in H$.
>
> ii. Prove that $\|T\|=\|h\|\|y\|$.
>
> iii. Prove that $\|A\|=\sinh1$, where $A$ is the operator on $L^2(0,1)$ defined by
> $$
>    (Ax)(t)=\int_0^1e^{t-s}x(s)ds;\qquad t\in(0,1).
> $$

For (i), if $\text{im }T=\text{span}\{y\}$ then I can write $Tx=cy$. Would I be able to use the Riesz representation theorem here somehow? As for (ii) and (iii), I am unsure how to begin.

Any tips on how to solve these problems? Thank you.

Comment: You can argue as in the proof of Riesz representation theorem for i. When the image is one dimensional it behave just like a linear functional.

Comment: $x \to c$ where $Tx=cy$ is a continuous linear functional on $H$. Apply Riesz Theorem to this functional.